# The problem Docker PHP-Redis and healthcheck

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, redis, health-check

I have two services. Redis and PHP. How to make php wait for the launch of redis and write about it.I tried using healthcheck-s but apparently I am not setting it up correctly.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: docker/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-7.0
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "8280:80"
    links:
      - redis:redis
  redis:
     build: docker/cache
     container_name: redis
```

Dockerfile-php-7.0

```
FROM php:7.0
RUN pecl install redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./index.php"]
EXPOSE 80


 index.php    
                                                                                  
<?php
echo 'Starting';
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect(getenv('host'), getenv('6379'));
var_dump($redis->incr('foo'));
?>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM redis:3.2-alpine
COPY conf/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
EXPOSE 6379
```

Don't be afraid to scold me. I am just starting to learn docker.
I would be very grateful for any help !!!

Comment: you can probably use depends_on for php service in docker-compse.yml. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the docker-compose.yml file that you can use:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: docker/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-7.0
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "8280:80"
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
  redis:
    build: docker/cache
    container_name: redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
```

I also change the PHP script (index.php) as follows:

```
<?php
echo 'Starting';
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('redis', '6379');
var_dump($redis->incr('foo'));
```

Now the whole stack works in my machine. I can connect redis container from php.

The php container log shows the following

```
docker logs -f php
Startingint(1)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot . It works. But I need the php application to wait before starting redis through the healtcheck mechanism. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hi @lehan1819mailru, I've changed the docker-compose.yml file in my answer. Please note that I changed the "version" in docker-compose.yml to 2.1